# How To Init Loader List

Tags: c#

```
   List<dontknow> Bootstrap = new List<dontknow>()  {
        new Helper();
        new Spells();
        new Logic();
        new HPSystem();
        new Troll();
        new MoveSystem(); };
        Bootstrap.Init();
```

What can I write to dontknow part? All the ones I've inited are classes, and they all have void Init() 
I tried doing a CustomList class and  List , it didn't work out. Thanks. You can share with me if you have another method. Sorry I'm yet a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

All of your classes must inherit from the same base class or interface

```
public interface IMyThing
{
    void Init();
}

public class Helper : IMyThing{ // implementation }
public class Spells : IMyThing{ // implementation }
//etc.
```

That could also be a base class such as `MyThingBase`

Then you use the interface/base class for the list

```
List<IMyThing> Bootstrap = new List<IMyThing>()  {
        new Helper();
        new Spells();
        new Logic();
        new HPSystem();
        new Troll();
        new MoveSystem(); };
```

You would then need to enumerate the list to call `Init`

```
BootStrap.ForEach(x => x.Init());
```

Comment: Yay! happy coding.